# How to import or convert an Adobe EPS /PDF file into Microsoft Expression Design for editing

Tags: vector, expression-blend, pdf-to-html

I use expression design by microsoft.

One limitation is the lack of import or convert from .EPF or PDF (an adobe file format) to Microsoft Expression to edit.

I wish microsoft would support this, but its just lacking for the last 3 yrs as of version 4.

Can you please provide some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only version of Expression Design that has some EPS support is the [June 2012 Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27579). I don't believe this version was ever finished. And, because Design is discontinued, I'm afraid it never will...